# При верстке проблема с выравниванием контент-блока по центру

Tags: html, css

У меня есть контентский блок. 818px в ширину.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="blocktop"></div>
      <div class="blockmiddle">
        <div class="blockcontent">
          Тестируем
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blockbottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И, в css:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0;
}
.block {
 width: 818px;
 }

.blocktop {
 width: 818px;
 height: 11px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url("img/topcontent.png");
 background-position: center;
}

.blockbottom {
 width: 818px;
 height: 11px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 background: url("img/downcontent.png") center;
 background-position: center;
}

.blockmiddle {
 width: 818px;
 background: url("img/content.png") repeat-y center;
 background-position: center;
}

.blockcontent {
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 818px;
 padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Перепробовал все что знал. Блок стоит слева =(.

Answer (score 4):

не нужно применять узконаправленные способы (а к таковым относится align="center" - потому что это уже бородатый "хак" для IE). кстати, никого не хотел обидеть.
тут несколько проблем:

1. первоочередная!!!надо понимать блочную модель, то есть надо читать. например, первый же стиль: `#container {width: 100%;...}`. все ходили в школу и, думаю, помнят, что % - это относительная величина. А это означает, что для вычисления количества процентов необходима величина относительно которой мы ведём отсчёт. ну вот и задайте размеры окна. я так понимаю, что Вы хотели реализовать "резиновый" макет. и я даже помню, как читал где-то, что для, чтобы получить резиновый макет - надо всего лишь заменить px на % в определении ширины и высоты. это НЕ ТАК! смысл тут прост: сначала мы задаём размеры окна, для которого свёрстана страница, а потом уже указываем сколько процентов занимают блоки от этого окна.
2. вторая же проблема является следствием первой - неправильное понимание блочной модели. для центрирования элемента достаточно написать `margin: 0 auto`. что это правило означает? этим мы задаём поля. как известно, существует 4 правила для задания полей и присвоение значений из краткой формы проходит по часовой стрелке - поле сверху, поле справа, поле снизу, поле слева. следовательно, элемент центрируется относительно родительского за счёт присвоения одинаковых значений для левого и правого полей. но у Вас ширина родительского и дочернего элемента равны 100%, то есть дочерний элемент занимает полную ширину родительского элемента. а что такое ширина элемента?это сумма величин подложки (padding), ширины (width), полей (margin), ширины рамок (border) слева и справа. получаем, чтобы у нас появилось пространство для полей, на основании которых элемент будет центрирован, надо уменьшить ширину центрируемого элемента (например на 80% от родительского).

вот и всё. длинновато получилось, конечно. чтобы было понятнее.

Answer (score 3):

Так, для начала лучше было бы написать какой именно блок нужно выровнять. Как я понял из контекста это блок с классом block. Для блока с фиксированной шириной есть отличное решение:

    `.block {
     left:50%;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: -409px;
     width: 818px;
    }`

Этот стиль рабочий. Советую Вам пользоваться гуглом перед тем как задать вопрос, потому как такая вещь довольно тривиальна и, что самое главное, ответ на неё находится в топе по запросу: "выравнивание div по центру экрана".

Answer (score 3):

Самое распространённое:

```
.someBlock{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
<div id="container" align="center">
```

Работает)