# Выравнивание блока по центру родительского блока

Tags: вёрстка, html

Привет. Нужно выравнить блок по центру родительского блока(один div вложен в другой), используя только CSS. Вне зависимости от того как мы указываем размеры блоков(проценты, пиксели, пункты или ещё что). Всё что нашёл в интернете не работает(смотрел в FF 6 и последнем Сhrome).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
    <div id="container" align="center">
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Да, этот код приведёт к выравниванию по горизонтали, но надо ещё и по вертикали.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте здесь [мой комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33645/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83)

У вас схожие проблемы. И советую, прежде чем задать вопрос - сначала посмотрите уже существующие темы на интересующую Вас тему.

Comment: Я не до конца понял тот ваш комментарий. Вы пишете про неправильное понимание "резинового" макета и утверждаете, что в "резиновом макете" у базового блока должна указываться размеры:"начала мы задаём размеры окна, для которого свёрстана страница, а потом уже указываем сколько процентов занимают блоки от этого окна." Это разве правда? Кстати, на сайте Лебедева лежит код, где производиться центрирование блока по горизонтали и оно работает для базового блока width:100%. Но как сделать универсальное(без применения параметров внутреннего блока) центрирование по вертикали. В этом и вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Да сделайте вы margin: 0 auto; выровняете по горизонтали. Задав "относительную" ширину блока, скажем 20% от высоты, вы сможете этот margin изменить на margin: 40% auto; и будет вас счастье!

Answer (score 0):

[text-align:](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-align)  и  [vertical-align:](http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align) и еще [вертикальное выравнивание](http://habrahabr.ru/post/73113/)