# Позиционирование блоков

Tags: css

Есть код (упрощенно):

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">Прижат ЛЕВО-ВЕРХ</div>
  <div id="right">Прижат ПРАВО-НИЗ</div>
</div>
```

Вот в очередной раз убеждаюсь, что у меня проблемы с css-позиционированием и кроссбраузерностью.

В общем задача: нужен css-код следующего характера. Блок main должен растягиваться по ширине исходя из ширины внутренних блоков. И по высоте так же исходя из наибольшей высоты внутреннего блока. Блок left-нужно прижать слева вверху относительно main. Блок right - справа внизу, так же относительно main.

Делал так:

```
div#main { position: relative; display: inline-block; width: auto}
div#left {width: 500px}
div#right {position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0}
```

Но в результате получается, что main растягивается по ширине всей страницы, а не по своему содержимому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я предлагаю 2 варианта решения Вашего вопроса (**для корректной работы во всех браузерах необходимо сменить кодировку**):
*Первый способ*: реализовано практически именно то, что Вам хотели реализовать изначально, итак:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Блоки</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset:windows-1251"/>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
    }
    div#main {
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#left {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    div#right {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-left: 398px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">Лево-вверх</div>
        <div id="right">Право-низ</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Высота блоков выстраивается в зависимости от высоты содержимого. а высота "главного" контейнера меняется в зависимости от высоты, содержащихся в нём левого и правого блоков. *В чём была проблема*: неправильное понимание понятий `auto` и `100%`. Иногда браузер рассматривает эти понятия идентичными. тем более, если Вы нигде не указываете абсолютных размеров (хотя бы для ширины и высоты всей страницы). Я уже как-то описывал эту ситуацию в каком из вопросов например [в этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33645/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#33705). можете почитать, если интересно. К тому же, использование абсолютных размеров помогает избежать большое количество "своих" толкований браузерами IE блочной модели, ибо после задания ширины или высоты элементу присвается свойство hasLayout и браузер практически перестаёт "шалить". В данном случае браузер понимает `width: auto` для блока `right`, как "занимай 100% ширины родительского блока". *Совет*: не брезгуйте абсолютными размерами. Даже, если хотите реализовать резиновую вёрстку.

*Второй способ*:

Второй способ реализует уже мою идею с плавающей моделью.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Блоки</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset:windows-1251"/>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
    }
    div#main {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div#left {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid green;
        float: left;
    }
    div#right {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 278px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">Лево-вверх</div>
        <div id="right">Право-низ</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Так как при плавающей модели плавающие блоки "извлекаются" из нормального потока - для корректной работы лучше задать фиксированную высоту родительского блока. Ну, чтобы "прижать" правый блок к низу - увеличиваем верхнее поле на нужное количество пикселей (в том числе и для этого необходимо знать высоту родительского блока). **стоит заметить**: для нормальной работы в браузерах IE необходимо наличие, так называемого, "очищающего" элемента. для него необходимо указать свойство `clear: both`. Ибо данный браузер ПО-СВОЕМУ понимает эту модель.

Вот, вроде, и всё, что я хотел написать! Надеюсь, мне удалось Вам помочь и благодарен за голоса))))

Comment: я пока с телефона сижу и не могу более подробно ответить,но можно попробовать задать фиксированные размеры родительского блока,вместо абсолютного позиционирования-двинуть правый нижний блок полями.

Comment: еще один вопрос:использование inline-block действительное оправдано?если нет-необходимости в нем нет.div и так блочный и добавлять ему поведение строчного элемента редко необходимо.

Comment: inline-block просто для пробы делал. Так то конечно, оно не обязательно. Я на самом деле уже что только пробывал, ничего не получается. Выставил внутренним блокам `float:left` - все, ширина родителя тянется по дочерним элементам. Но теперь не могу правый блок прижать к низу. Ну и как-бы все это выглядит хорошо только в нормальных браузерах. В IE дочерние блоки друг под другом находятся.

Comment: правому выставьте float:right,а к низу прижмите верхним полем(для этого надо знать высоту родительского блока).чтобы в ие нормально работала плавающая модель необходимо наличие 'очищающего' элемента,который будет отменять это поведение.т.е.надо добавить элемент с clear:both

Comment: я думаю,что этот совет вряд ли нужен,но указание корректного доктайпа очень важно и помогает решить множество проблем

Comment: К сожалению ни один ни другой из ваших вариантов не работает как надо. 1-й: оба блока прижаты к ТОПу родителя. 2-й: у правого блока надо указывать margin-top, который всегда разный, т.к. высота левого блока не постоянна.